# Registering custom shell function in system (OSX)

Tags: function, shell, bash

today I wanted to write a function which will deploy my blog page (developed in nanoc) to github pages automatically - here's the script:

```
function cmit()
{
  nanoc compile;
  git add .;
  git commit -am $1;
  git push origin source;
  cd output; git add .;
  git commit -am $1;
  git push origin master;
  cd ..;
  echo 'new version deployed! now starting nanoc locally..';
  nanoc aco;
}
```

Example usage: `cmit "my example commit!"`

I don't really know how register my function in system (OSX) - in `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` or maybe somewhere else? Please help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just added it to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file then you will be able to use `cmit` like a regular command, you will need to refresh your current shell to pick up the changes so run `source ~/.bashrc`. If you have the function saved in a file `cmit` just do `cat cmit >> ~/.bashrc` to append the function to the end of your `~/.bashrc`.

You could try out a test function first:

```
# add to ~/.bashrc first
function test() {
    echo "Some test foo!"
}

$ source ~/.bashrc

$ test
Some test foo!
```

Comment: it doesn't work when I restart console - how to register it once and for all (now I have every time run `source` command after opening console..) :(

Comment: It seems on OSX `~/.bashprofile` is used instead of `~.bashrc` so put the function in `~/.bashprofile` and that should solve it.

Comment: *cough*ehem* `~/.bash_profile` there is an underscore.

Answer (score 4):

You can put it in your `.bashrc`, it will work as long as you're logged as the owner of this `.bashrc` file.

If you want it to be available for any user, put the content of your function in a script file, make it executable using `chmod` then move it in `/usr/bin` (I'm assuming you have admin rights on that system)

Note: typically you'd give it `rwx rx rx` rights, which corresponds to a `chmod 755 my_script`

EDIT:

> can you create your own lets say .my_bashrc and somehow tell system to
>   look in that file as well?

Yes you could, just tell your `.bashrc` to source your file:

```
source ~/my_files/.my_bashrc
```

or

```
. ~/my_files/.my_bashrc
```